# Where can I find my user data to insert in `npm adduser`?

Tags: npm, package

I was under organization and I published packages successfully, I had a few issue so I clear the cache and now I try to publish a package and I get:

```
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

before the clear it worked perfectly, where I can find the data to login again?